# Pluralization issue in the tags new design page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, plurals

There is a pluralization issue in the [Tags new design page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new).
When there is only one question for the tag, it is showing as `1 questions`.
It should be displayed as `1 question`.

> [image: Tags]

Comment: The deprecated Giant-S strikes back ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pluralization issue has been fixed in the Tags page.
Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Fixed]